# Bootstrap-alert dismisses parent container

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, haml

Bootstrap-alert plugin works really strange. I have following haml structure:

```
.flashes
  .message.fade.in
    %p Hi there!
```

And some coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.flashes').on 'click', '.message', ->
    $(this).alert('close')
```

Pretty simple. I expect that calling `alert('close')` will dismiss only clicked `.message` element. But plugin closes entire `.flashes` block. Can't figure out, what's wrong with it. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `$(x).alert('close')` expects `x` to be a close button – not the actual alert box – so it closes `x`'s parent element. For example, give this HTML:

```
<div class="flashes">
    <div class="message fade in">
        <p>Hi <span>there!</span></p>
        <p>Where is pancakes house?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CoffeeScript:

```
$('.flashes').on 'click', '.message', ->
    $(@).find('span').alert('close')​​​
```

a click will close the first `<p>` and leave `.flashes`, `.message`, and the second `<p>` alone.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JJbCz/

But if you change the CoffeeScript to `.alert('close')` on the the first child:

```
$('.flashes').on 'click', '.message', ->
    $(@).find(':first-child').alert('close')
```

then you should get the results you're expecting.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wm6jh/

I don't see anywhere that you're wrapping anything in an alert (i.e. `$(x).alert()`) so perhaps you're just abusing `.alert('close')` for and should be using a simple manual [`.fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) call:

```
$('.flashes').on 'click', '.message', ->
    $(@).fadeOut('slow')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uhV6P/

​